# putty で接続した ubuntu 上で emacs を起動すると、とても見づらい

Tags: emacs, putty

Putty で接続した ubuntu 上で、 emacs を起動すると、とても見づらいです。たとえば、 list-packages の画面は添付ファイルのような状態で、肝心のパッケージ名が一見しただけではまったくわかりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これを、見やすくするためには、どうしたらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTYの設定で、色を変えるのが良いのでは無いでしょうか？

メニューの`Change Setting...`から変更することが可能です。詳しくは、以下のサイトが参考になるかと思われます。

PuTTYの青文字が見づらいので変更する方法 - Qiita  
http://qiita.com/takanemu/items/04641ce510a605c5835e

Answer (score 1):

既に回答は出ていますが、Emacs 側で変更する方法を紹介しておきます。

既にご存知かも知れませんが、Emacs では `face` と呼んでいるモノでテキストの表示形式を変更する事が可能です。

まず、パッケージリストにおけるパッケージ名の `face` は `package-name` です。

**lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el**

```emacs-lisp
;;; Package menu faces
(defface package-name
  '((t :inherit link))
  "Face used on package names in the package menu."
  :version "25.1")
```

`:inherit` は言葉通りの意味で、`link` という名前の `face` の属性をそっくりそのまま受け継ぎます。その `link face` ですが、`face.el` で定義されています。

**lisp/face.el**

```emacs-lisp
(defface link
  '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light))
     :foreground "RoyalBlue3" :underline t)
    (((class color) (background light))
     :foreground "blue" :underline t)
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark))
     :foreground "cyan1" :underline t)
    (((class color) (background dark))
     :foreground "cyan" :underline t)
    (t :inherit underline))
  "Basic face for unvisited links."
  :group 'basic-faces
  :version "22.1")
```

PuTTY が background color を変更しなければ `RoyalBlue3` か `blue` になります(Inoue さんの回答にある screenshot の様に)。

一応、`package-name face` の `foreground color` を変更する方法を書いておきます。

```emacs-lisp
(add-hook 'package-menu-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (set-face-attribute 'package-name nil :foreground "red")))
```

これを Emacs の start-up ファイルに入れておくとパッケージ名の部分の `foreground color` が赤色になります(PuTTY が色相を調整する場合は暗赤色になるかと思います)。

Answer (score 0):

Change Settings -> Window -> Colours -> Use system colours にチェックをつけると、なぜかはよくわかりませんが、見やすくはなりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]